# Regex for 10-13 digit (international) phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to deliver (international) phone numbers from a PHP registration form to an external party. The external party has the following rules for phone numbers.

- 10-13 digits
- dashes are allowed

This means the following numbers are correct

- 0046701234567 *(Swedish)*
- 604-555-5555
- 5675555555

What would be the best (and most correct) regex to regulate and check all the phone numbers so I can store them in a global database to send them to the external party afterwards?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input = '604-555-5555';

if (preg_match('/^\d{10,13}$/', str_replace('-', '', $input))) {
  // valid
}
```

Comment: Sometimes is the answer so obvious that you are ashamed for asking.

Comment: @Hidde If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the thick on the left.

Comment: @CodeJockey Questions ? ;-)

Comment: I couldn't accept the answer because Stackoverflow has a time limit for accepting answers @hsz. Done now.

Comment: And @CodeJockey, have some faith in new users without reputation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $input = '604-555-5555';  
  if (preg_match('/[\d-]{10,13}+/', $input, $r) ) {
    // valid
    foreach($r as $e){echo $e;}do formatting      
  } 
?>
```

Comment: yeah i have but very basic. iv learnt something new thanks to hsz and m42 indirecly :)

Comment: It will match `123456------------123456789-----------`